# How can I use angular-material with CSP?

Tags: angularjs, content-security-policy, angularjs-material

Our Content Security Policy does not allow `unsafe-inline` for styles.

When I try to use angular-material in our application, it won't work right (missing styles) and I get a lot of errors logged in the DevTools. From what I can tell, this is due to dynamically generated CSS being injected into the page.

I'm already including [ngCsp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp), but it has no noticeably effect on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation at [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/api/service/$mdThemingProvider) the solution must be:

```
angular
.module("app", ['ngMaterial'])
.config(['$mdThemingProvider', function (themeProv) {
    themeProv.setNonce('randomString')
}])
```

> The nonce to be added as an attribute to the theme style tags. Setting a value allows the use of CSP policy without using the unsafe-inline directive.

Comment: This works but does not yet add a nonce attribute for this style tag I saw was added by angularjs: `<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak]...</style>`